# Gaussian Elimination $(Q-I)S = 0$, $Q$ is rotation matrix and $S$ is a vector

Tags: linear-algebra

I need to solve this question where I have to compute $(Q-I)S = 0$ and do Gaussian elimination to solve for $S$. The problem is I do not know how to do Gaussian elimination on a rotation matrix. Theta is unknown.

$Q$ is a 3x3 rotation matrix and $S$ is a general column vector.

Comment: How large is the matrix? Can you add it to the question?

Comment: The question doesnt say but I think we should it assumes is 3x3